# Correcting Gmail's "sign-in attempt blocked"

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I need my application to be able to log on to Gmail and send email on behalf of the user. The user supplies credentials. However, when I do so I get this message from Gmail:

```
Subject: Google Account: sign-in attempt blocked
Hi Jessica, 

We recently blocked a sign-in attempt to your Google Account [...]. 

...

If this was you you can switch to an app made by Google such as Gmail
to access your account (recommended) or change your settings at     
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps so that your
account is no longer protected by modern security standards.
```

I would like my app to "protect users by modern security standards" but nowhere do I find any data on what "modern security standards" means in this context. The app uses SSL, user name and password.

The app works if you do click the link, but I really don't want my users to have to click the "lesssecureapps" link, though if that is the only option, so be it. But I'd rather modify my app to be compliant with what Gmail needs. However, nowhere does it say what I am missing.

Any help please? I want to do the right thing.

Comment: I am a user and find this "feature" to only get in my way. There is no working way to get through it uf it decides to activate.